# How does $\frac{-1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \frac{-1}{k+1}$ helps to show that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\frac1{i^2}\leq \ 2-\frac{1}{k}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, summation, notation, induction

[image: Reference: https://i.imgur.com/xlD2aI9.png]

I can see why $\frac{-1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \frac{-1}{k+1}$ holds: multiplying both sides of the inequality by $(k+1)$ allows me to simplify to the form $\frac{1}{k+1} \leq \frac{1}{k}$, but it's unclear to me why 
$\frac{-1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \frac{-1}{k+1}$ 
is sufficient to show that
$\sum_{i=1}^ki + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq \ 2-\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1^2)}$.

Comment: The title was absurd and I modified it. Remaining are some serious typos in the body. Also, a reference of the book the page this is asking about is taken from should be given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, we do not *want* to show that
$$\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}.$$

Instead, the thing we must show in the inductive case is
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{k+1}. \tag1
$$

Prior to the point where you had your doubts, the proof had already
shown that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i^2} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq 2 + \left( -\frac{1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right).  \tag2
$$
Can you see how Inequality $(2)$, plus the fact that
$-\dfrac{1}{k}+\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq -\dfrac{1}{k+1}$,
is enough to prove Inequality $(1)$?

Comment: Is it because $2+\frac{-1}{k+1} \leq 2+(\frac{-1}{k}+\frac{1}{(k+1)^2})$? That makes sense, but only if we know that the summation of $\frac{1}{i^2}$ from $i=1$ to $k$ is less than $2$ to begin with. Why do we know that?

Comment: No, you have the inequality backward in that comment. Oh, and by the way, in the inductive step we _do_ know that the sum of $1/i^2$ from $1$ to $k$ is less than $2$, in fact less than $2-1/k$. That was the inductive assumption. The inductive assumption is _always_ justified during the inductive step. That is how induction works.